# Sharing Zod inferred types between frontend and backend

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, zod

I'm building a fullstack Express/React app. The app has a client, server and shared folder. The shared folder contains types shared between the frontend and backend like:

```
export interface NewUser {
  email: string;
  name?: string;
  address?: string;
}
```

This works fine, but I would like to use Zod. Is it possible to share types in the same way if I generate them using Zod? The first issue is that I can't import zod in the shared directory as Zod is installed in only the client and server directories. Is there a better way to go about this besides creating an npm package? Please help.

Comment: Why can't you import Zod in the shared folder? You can just reference either the client or server Zod packages, or just install Zod for a third time (ew). Or just install Zod only once in the first place and have the client and server use the same package.

Comment: Have you tried monorepos?

Comment: I'm looking into lerna, but I don't want to add more complexity if it's not necessary